# Events Logs in Mysql

Tags: mysql

```
    date_time               status

2023-05-01 00:00:33         Run1
2023-05-01 00:10:33         Run1
2023-05-01 00:12:33         Run1
2023-05-01 00:20:33         Fault1
2023-05-01 00:30:33         Run1
2023-05-01 00:40:33         Run1
2023-05-01 00:50:33         Fault2
2023-05-01 00:52:33         Fault2
2023-05-01 00:53:33         Run1
2023-05-01 00:54:33         Fault3
2023-05-01 00:54:33         Fault3
```

I want all changes logs that is not the repeated one. Only changes of the status. I want the following result

```
2023-05-01 00:00:33         Run1
2023-05-01 00:20:33         Fault1
2023-05-01 00:30:33         Run1
2023-05-01 00:50:33         Fault2
2023-05-01 00:53:33         Run1
2023-05-01 00:54:33         Fault3
```

I tried inner join for this result but not getting the proper result

Comment: So that's what you want. What's stopping you getting it? See [ask]

Comment: i am unable to find the suitable query

Comment: is this a SQL query result sir?

Comment: yes sir i want this result

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using? If you have a version that supports Window functions there is a solution using that feature.

Comment: I am using Mysql Version 5.7.23-23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  date_time DATETIME,
  status VARCHAR(8)
  );
INSERT INTO test VALUES
('2023-05-01 00:00:33', 'Run1'),
('2023-05-01 00:10:33', 'Run1'),
('2023-05-01 00:12:33', 'Run1'),
('2023-05-01 00:20:33', 'Fault1'),
('2023-05-01 00:30:33', 'Run1'),
('2023-05-01 00:40:33', 'Run1'),
('2023-05-01 00:50:33', 'Fault2'),
('2023-05-01 00:52:33', 'Fault2'),
('2023-05-01 00:53:33', 'Run1'),
('2023-05-01 00:54:33', 'Fault3'),
('2023-05-01 00:54:33', 'Fault3');
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| date_time | status |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-01 00:00:33 | Run1 |
| 2023-05-01 00:10:33 | Run1 |
| 2023-05-01 00:12:33 | Run1 |
| 2023-05-01 00:20:33 | Fault1 |
| 2023-05-01 00:30:33 | Run1 |
| 2023-05-01 00:40:33 | Run1 |
| 2023-05-01 00:50:33 | Fault2 |
| 2023-05-01 00:52:33 | Fault2 |
| 2023-05-01 00:53:33 | Run1 |
| 2023-05-01 00:54:33 | Fault3 |
| 2023-05-01 00:54:33 | Fault3 |

```
SELECT date_time, status
FROM (
    SELECT @prev <> status flag,
           date_time,
           @prev := status status
    FROM test
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev := '') init
    ORDER BY date_time
    ) subquery
WHERE flag
```

| date_time | status |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-05-01 00:00:33 | Run1 |
| 2023-05-01 00:20:33 | Fault1 |
| 2023-05-01 00:30:33 | Run1 |
| 2023-05-01 00:50:33 | Fault2 |
| 2023-05-01 00:53:33 | Run1 |
| 2023-05-01 00:54:33 | Fault3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wy9LqPet)